# Apache Camel context getting stopped automatically

Tags: java, plugins, apache-camel

I have a weird issue. Everything works perfectly when i run from IDE. Camel context gets stopped automatically when i run from console. What is causing the issue?

Logs attached.

`10:04:22.015 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Found 3 packages with 16 @Converter classes to load 10:04:22.079 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/projects/project/BS/distribution/target/org-bin.tar/org-bin/Plugins/project.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter 10:04:22.088 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - No additional package names found in classpath for annotated type converters. 10:04:22.089 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.i.c.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 182 type converters 2017-04-19 10:04:22.097 [Thread-3] INFO  project - Routes added 10:04:22.099 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: DataCollectorContext) is starting 10:04:22.101 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using ClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultClassResolver@6bac7e25, PackageScanClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver@1a0481c5, ApplicationContextClassLoader=null 10:04:22.101 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching is enabled on CamelContext: DataCollectorContext 10:04:22.103 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.m.DefaultManagementStrategy - JMX is disabled 10:04:22.115 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.SharedProducerServicePool - Starting service pool: org.apache.camel.impl.SharedProducerServicePool@4cf1dba5 10:04:22.115 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.SharedPollingConsumerServicePool - Starting service pool: org.apache.camel.impl.SharedPollingConsumerServicePool@7257f81d 10:04:22.125 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver@205acc67 to resolve component with name: seda 10:04:22.126 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: seda in registry: null 10:04:22.131 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: seda via type: org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaComponent via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/seda 10:04:22.152 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[seda://aggregate], path=[aggregate] 10:04:22.162 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - seda://aggregate converted to endpoint: Endpoint[seda://aggregate] by component: org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaComponent@2be155b8 10:04:22.163 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaComponent - Created queue seda://aggregate with size null 10:04:22.163 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.component.seda.SedaEndpoint - Endpoint Endpoint[seda://aggregate] is using shared queue: seda://aggregate with size: 2147483647 10:04:22.215 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'SetHeader[id, constant{n/a}]' 10:04:22.266 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never], path=[process] 10:04:22.270 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.DefaultTypeConverter - Promoting fallback type converter as a known type converter to convert from: org.apache.camel.WaitForTaskToComplete to: java.lang.String for the fallback converter: org.apache.camel.impl.converter.EnumTypeConverter@42fd1257 10:04:22.271 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: waitForTaskToComplete on bean: Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] with value: Never 10:04:22.272 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never converted to endpoint: Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] by component: org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaComponent@2be155b8 10:04:22.272 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaComponent - Created queue seda://process with size null 10:04:22.272 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.component.seda.SedaEndpoint - Endpoint Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] is using shared queue: seda://process with size: 2147483647 10:04:22.275 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'To[seda:process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]' 10:04:22.292 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'Aggregate[header(id) -> [To[seda:process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]]]' 10:04:22.303 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[seda://process], path=[process] 10:04:22.303 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - seda://process converted to endpoint: Endpoint[seda://process] by component: org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaComponent@2be155b8 10:04:22.304 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaComponent - Reusing existing queue seda://process with size null and reference count 2 10:04:22.304 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.component.seda.SedaEndpoint - Endpoint Endpoint[seda://process] is using shared queue: seda://process with size: 2147483647 10:04:22.308 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'process[Processor@0x71ed8637]' 10:04:22.310 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never], path=[cloud] 10:04:22.311 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: waitForTaskToComplete on bean: Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] with value: Never 10:04:22.312 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never converted to endpoint: Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] by component: org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaComponent@2be155b8 10:04:22.312 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaComponent - Created queue seda://cloud with size null 10:04:22.312 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.component.seda.SedaEndpoint - Endpoint Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] is using shared queue: seda://cloud with size: 2147483647 10:04:22.313 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'To[seda:cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]' 10:04:22.314 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[seda://cloud], path=[cloud] 10:04:22.315 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - seda://cloud converted to endpoint: Endpoint[seda://cloud] by component: org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaComponent@2be155b8 10:04:22.315 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaComponent - Reusing existing queue seda://cloud with size null and reference count 2 10:04:22.315 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.component.seda.SedaEndpoint - Endpoint Endpoint[seda://cloud] is using shared queue: seda://cloud with size: 2147483647 10:04:22.318 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'process[Processor@0x8b29880]' 10:04:22.320 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver@205acc67 to resolve component with name: rest 10:04:22.321 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: rest in registry: null 10:04:22.322 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: rest via type: org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestComponent via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/rest 10:04:22.326 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[rest://post:api/v1:/datacollector?componentName=restlet&consumes=application%2Foctet-stream&routeId=Data+Collector+Inlet], path=[post:api/v1:/datacollector] 10:04:22.327 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: componentName on bean: Endpoint[rest://post:api/v1:/datacollector?componentName=restlet&consumes=application%2Foctet-stream&routeId=Data+Collector+Inlet] with value: restlet 10:04:22.328 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: consumes on bean: Endpoint[rest://post:api/v1:/datacollector?componentName=restlet&consumes=application%2Foctet-stream&routeId=Data+Collector+Inlet] with value: application/octet-stream 10:04:22.328 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: routeId on bean: Endpoint[rest://post:api/v1:/datacollector?componentName=restlet&consumes=application%2Foctet-stream&routeId=Data+Collector+Inlet] with value: Data Collector Inlet 10:04:22.330 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - rest://post:api/v1:/datacollector?componentName=restlet&consumes=application%2Foctet-stream&routeId=Data+Collector+Inlet converted to endpoint: Endpoint[rest://post:api/v1:/datacollector?componentName=restlet&consumes=application%2Foctet-stream&routeId=Data+Collector+Inlet] by component: org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestComponent@647c8a45 10:04:22.337 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'RestBinding' 10:04:22.340 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[seda://aggregate?waitForTaskToComplete=Never], path=[aggregate] 10:04:22.340 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: waitForTaskToComplete on bean: Endpoint[seda://aggregate?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] with value: Never 10:04:22.341 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - seda://aggregate?waitForTaskToComplete=Never converted to endpoint: Endpoint[seda://aggregate?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] by component: org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaComponent@2be155b8 10:04:22.341 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaComponent - Reusing existing queue seda://aggregate with size null and reference count 2 10:04:22.341 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.component.seda.SedaEndpoint - Endpoint Endpoint[seda://aggregate?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] is using shared queue: seda://aggregate with size: 2147483647 10:04:22.341 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.p.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'To[seda:aggregate?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]' 10:04:22.342 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance. 10:04:22.346 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy - Created spool directory: C:\Users\310103~1\AppData\Local\Temp\camel\camel-tmp-4fc4d293-9e75-4dc4-967d-c97fbff9a725 10:04:22.347 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy - StreamCaching configuration DefaultStreamCachingStrategy[spoolDirectory=C:\Users\310103~1\AppData\Local\Temp\camel\camel-tmp-4fc4d293-9e75-4dc4-967d-c97fbff9a725, spoolChiper=null, spoolThreshold=131072, spoolUsedHeapMemoryThreshold=0, bufferSize=4096, anySpoolRules=false] 10:04:22.347 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.i.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy - StreamCaching in use with spool directory: C:\Users\310103~1\AppData\Local\Temp\camel\camel-tmp-4fc4d293-9e75-4dc4-967d-c97fbff9a725 and rules: [Spool > 128K body size] 10:04:22.348 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Warming up route id: Message Aggregation having autoStartup=true 10:04:22.349 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting services on route: Message Aggregation 10:04:22.351 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Pipeline[[Channel[SetHeader(id, n/a)], Channel[AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]]]] 10:04:22.353 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.c.p.aggregate.AggregateProcessor - Defaulting to MemoryAggregationRepository 10:04:22.360 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaProducer - Starting producer: Producer[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] 10:04:22.360 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache - Adding to producer cache with key: Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] for producer: Producer[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] 10:04:22.361 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Pipeline[[Channel[SetHeader(id, n/a)], Channel[AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]]]] 10:04:22.361 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> SetHeader(id, n/a) 10:04:22.361 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[SetHeader(id, n/a)] 10:04:22.362 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]] 10:04:22.362 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]] 10:04:22.362 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])] 10:04:22.362 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]) 10:04:22.362 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])] 10:04:22.363 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Warming up route id: Meta Data Enricher having autoStartup=true 10:04:22.363 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting services on route: Meta Data Enricher 10:04:22.364 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Pipeline[[Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637]], Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]] 10:04:22.364 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaProducer - Starting producer: Producer[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] 10:04:22.364 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache - Adding to producer cache with key: Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] for producer: Producer[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] 10:04:22.365 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Pipeline[[Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637]], Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]] 10:04:22.365 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637] 10:04:22.365 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637]] 10:04:22.365 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]) 10:04:22.365 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])] 10:04:22.366 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Warming up route id: xmpp Messenger having autoStartup=true 10:04:22.366 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting services on route: xmpp Messenger 10:04:22.366 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: xmpp Messenger -> Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.xmppMessenger@8b29880]] 10:04:22.366 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: xmpp Messenger -> DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.xmppMessenger@8b29880] 10:04:22.366 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: xmpp Messenger -> Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.xmppMessenger@8b29880]] 10:04:22.367 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Warming up route id: Data Collector Inlet having autoStartup=true 10:04:22.367 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting services on route: Data Collector Inlet 10:04:22.367 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver@205acc67 to resolve component with name: restlet 10:04:22.367 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: restlet in registry: null 10:04:22.372 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: restlet via type: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/restlet 10:04:22.609 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: persistingConnections on bean: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent@12bb40f7 with value: true 10:04:22.609 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: pipeliningConnections on bean: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent@12bb40f7 with value: true 10:04:22.609 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: maxQueued on bean: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent@12bb40f7 with value: -1 10:04:22.613 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[restlet://http://localhost:1785/api/v1/datacollector?restletMethods=POST], path=[http://localhost:1785/api/v1/datacollector] 10:04:22.616 [Thread-3] INFO  o.a.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: DataCollectorContext) is shutting down 10:04:22.616 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager - Shutting down with no inflight threads. 10:04:22.616 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Stopping services on route: Data Collector Inlet 10:04:22.616 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down services on route: Data Collector Inlet 10:04:22.617 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Stopping services on route: xmpp Messenger 10:04:22.617 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: xmpp Messenger -> SedaConsumer[Endpoint[seda://cloud]] 10:04:22.617 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: xmpp Messenger -> Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.xmppMessenger@8b29880]] 10:04:22.617 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: xmpp Messenger -> DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.xmppMessenger@8b29880] 10:04:22.617 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: xmpp Messenger -> Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.xmppMessenger@8b29880]] 10:04:22.617 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down services on route: xmpp Messenger 10:04:22.618 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Stopping services on route: Meta Data Enricher 10:04:22.618 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> SedaConsumer[Endpoint[seda://process]] 10:04:22.618 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Pipeline[[Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637]], Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]] 10:04:22.618 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaProducer - Stopping producer: Producer[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] 10:04:22.618 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Pipeline[[Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637]], Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]] 10:04:22.619 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637] 10:04:22.619 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Channel[DelegateSync[com.org.unit.server.plugin.MetaDataEnricher@71ed8637]] 10:04:22.619 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]) 10:04:22.619 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Meta Data Enricher -> Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://cloud?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])] 10:04:22.619 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down services on route: Meta Data Enricher 10:04:22.619 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Stopping services on route: Message Aggregation 10:04:22.620 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> SedaConsumer[Endpoint[seda://aggregate]] 10:04:22.620 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Pipeline[[Channel[SetHeader(id, n/a)], Channel[AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]]]] 10:04:22.620 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.component.seda.SedaProducer - Stopping producer: Producer[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never] 10:04:22.620 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Pipeline[[Channel[SetHeader(id, n/a)], Channel[AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]]]] 10:04:22.620 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> SetHeader(id, n/a) 10:04:22.620 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[SetHeader(id, n/a)] 10:04:22.620 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]] 10:04:22.621 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.a.c.i.DefaultExecutorServiceManager - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.SynchronousExecutorService@43e17e83 10:04:22.622 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[AggregateProcessor[to: Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]]] 10:04:22.622 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])] 10:04:22.622 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never]) 10:04:22.622 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Shutting down child service on route: Message Aggregation -> Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[seda://process?waitForTaskToComplete=Never])]`

Comment: @10:04:22.616 camelcontext stops

Comment: Please provide additional information about how your context is created and started in application.

Comment: some information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488805/apache-camel-typeconvertor-packaging?noredirect=1#comment74032562_43488805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with TypeConvertor in packaging. All the files were not getting downloaded from maven. Used maven-assembly-plugin to make a jar with dependencies.