# Apache Camel Typeconvertor packaging

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

When i run it in the IDE , it worked fine .. But when i run it in console i got the below Exception

> Error in App initializePluginorg.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: restlet://http://localhost:1705/api/v1/app?restletMethods=POST due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: restletMethods as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.restlet.data.Method[] with value POST

While comparing the logs of the two cases i see that somehow typeconvertors are not getting loaded.

IDE log -- which works fine

> 09:23:20.654 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Found 3 packages with 16 @Converter classes to load
>   09:23:20.747 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.1/camel-core-2.17.1.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
>   09:23:20.749 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-spring/2.17.1/camel-spring-2.17.1.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
>   09:23:20.751 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-restlet/2.17.1/camel-restlet-2.17.1.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
>   09:23:20.752 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-http4/2.17.1/camel-http4-2.17.1.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
>   09:23:20.754 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-http-common/2.17.1/camel-http-common-2.17.1.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
>   09:23:20.779 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loaded 5 @Converter classes
>   09:23:20.837 [main] INFO  o.a.c.i.c.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 196 type converters

Console log -- which throws the exception

> 12:06:41.741 [CamelThread] DEBUG
>   o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Found 3 packages with 16
>   @Converter classes to load 12:06:41.806 [CamelThread] DEBUG
>   o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file
>   META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of
>   packages, from url:
>   jar:file:/C:/projects/user/org/distribution/target/blah.tar/blah/Plugins/blahblah.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
>   12:06:41.812 [CamelThread] DEBUG
>   o.a.c.i.c.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - No additional package names
>   found in classpath for annotated type converters. 12:06:41.813
>   [CamelThread] INFO  o.a.c.i.c.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 182 type
>   converter

pom file 

    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.org.unit.proj</groupId>
<artifactId>blahblah</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <resource.path.proj>${project.build.directory}/dependencies/proj/</resource.path.proj>

    <projDistributionPkgVersion>1.0.1</projDistributionPkgVersion>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camel.version>2.17.1</camel.version>
    <cbor.version>0.5</cbor.version>

</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.org.team</groupId>
    <artifactId>master-build-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.org.unit</groupId>
        <artifactId>proj-name-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>${projDistributionPkgVersion}</version>
        <type>tar.gz</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.org.unit.proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>proj-name-main</artifactId>
        <version>${projDistributionPkgVersion}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${resource.path.proj}proj-name-main.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>co.nstant.in</groupId>
        <artifactId>cbor</artifactId>
        <version>${cbor.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>blahblah</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Include dependency plugins in final jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.org.unit</groupId>
                                <artifactId>proj-name-distribution</artifactId>
                                <version>${projDistributionPkgVersion}</version>
                                <type>tar.gz</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${resource.path.proj}</outputDirectory>
                                <includes>*.jar</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

How do you package it correctly ? Is there a way to i can specify in pom to include typeconvertors specifically ?

Comment: You should show how you package your app and how you run it.

Comment: updated .. camel routes are written inside the code (as of now)..

Comment: One more update: if i move these camel dependencies to my parent application pom(proj-name-main) , it works ...